Deleting watchOS app causes CoreLocation permission to reset in iOS companion app
I have an iOS app where in onboarding I ask for the user's location before proceeding to the app:
let manager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

And I have a companion watchOS app that does the same if it hasn't been granted already by the iOS app. It is shared code/shared permission.
For some reason I can't understand, when I delete the watchOS app, the permission of my iOS app is reset to .notDetermined.
func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        switch manager.authorizationStatus {
#if os(macOS)
        case .authorized:
            // Authorized is only available on macOS
            self.permission = .granted(.always)
#endif
        case .authorizedAlways:
            self.permission = .granted(.always)
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            self.permission = .granted(.whenInUse)
        case .notDetermined:
            self.permission = .undecided
        case .restricted, .denied:
            self.permission = .denied
        default:
            self.permission = .undecided
        }
    }


Did you try asking for location permission separately on both apps (iOS and watchOS)?
#if is(iOS)
func requestLocationPermissionForiOS() {
}
#elseif os(watchOS)
func requestLocationPermissionForWatchOS() {
}
#endif

This might solve your problem, because now are you asking for location permission in both platforms, Previously you asked for shared permissions.

Not sure I am following your suggestion. What would I put inside these blocks? It's the same code to request permission on both platforms:
manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

Yes,  same code, the idea is to call manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization for both platforms.
